# why parseInt("0x") return NaN

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, when we use parseInt(parameter)，js will return a num which parse by the string parameter.

it parse the string until the first char can't become a num.

such as

```
console.log(parseInt("024x2")) // 24
console.log(parseInt("0b")) // 0
```

but

```
console.log(parseInt("0x")) // NaN
```

why not ?

```
console.log(parseInt("0x")) // 0
```

I know 0x means Hexadecimal

Comment: The [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript) function parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems).

Comment: I don't think the linked answer is a duplicate at all. Sure, it says that "0x" is meant to represent hex, but it doesn't explain the behavior of parseInt.

Comment: No worries, I reopened it.

Comment: @Durga: That question still isn't a duplicate - the linked question doesn't ask about `parseInt("0x")` and none of the answers explain why that returns NaN.

Answer (score 1):

use `parseInt("0x", 10)` to force decimal system, since otherwise:

> If radix is undefined or 0 (or absent), JavaScript assumes the following:
>
> If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", radix is 16 (hexadecimal) >and the remainder of the string is parsed.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat explained in the [Mozilla reference documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) (emphasis mine):

> If `parseInt` encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. `parseInt` truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.
>
> ...
>
> If `radix` is undefined or 0 (or absent), JavaScript assumes the following:
>
> - If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", `radix` is 16 (hexadecimal) **and the remainder of the string is parsed**.
> - If the input string begins with "0", `radix` is eight (octal) or 10 (decimal).  Exactly which radix is chosen is implementation-dependent.  ECMAScript 5 specifies that 10 (decimal) is used, but not all browsers support this yet.  For this reason always specify a radix when using `parseInt`.
> - If the input string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal).
>
> If the first character cannot be converted to a number, `parseInt` returns `NaN`.

Note how the first bullet point is different to the rest - it says "the remainder of the string is parsed". I take that to mean:

```
parseInt("0xfoo")
```

is treated as equivalent to

```
parseInt("foo", 16)
```

regardless of what "foo" is - in your case. So `parseInt("0x")` is equivalent to `parseInt("", 16)`.

So, here are your examples and an explanation of the output:

```
// radix is inferred as 8 or 10 (implementation-dependent)
// Parsing stops at "x" which is invalid in either radix.
// The first character was valid, so the result is 24 or 18.
parseInt("024x2")

// radix is inferred as 8 or 10 (implementation-dependent)
// Parsing stops at "b" which is invalid in either radix.
// The first character was valid, so the result is 0.
parseInt("0b")

// radix is inferred as 16, but then parsing *restarts* at
// an empty string. There's no valid first character at this
// point, so the result is NaN
parseInt("0x")
```

The [ECMA standard provides much more detail](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-parseint-string-radix) but the Mozilla description is probably simpler to understand. The ECMA version corresponds with my understanding of "the remainder of the string is parsed" too - see step 10 of the description.

Answer (score 0):

`0x` is the beginning of a hexadecimal number. You're getting `NaN` because you have the prefix, but it's not followed by any digits that specify the value of the number.

Comment: Wasn't this supposed to mark as duplicate?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal That happened right after I posted.

Comment: That fine, It happens :)

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

While using `parseInt`,

> If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", radix is 16 (hexadecimal) and the remainder of the string is parsed.

Since there is nothing present after *radix*, you are getting `NaN`.